# Change headers for one custom PHP file

Tags: php, headers

I have a `server.php` file that I wish to host on the same server as my Wordpress site, that is required to send a POST message with a header of `Content-type: application/json`.

Wordpress is preventing me to use `<?php header("ContentType : application/json"); ?>` and doing so, it redirects to some file on `https://site/wp-json/`, which is not what I want.

Tried using the below code in the same file, but then it returns HTTP 500 Internal server error:

```
function changeHeaders($headers) {

    $headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    return $headers; 
}

add_filter('wp_headers', 'changeHeaders');
```

How do I change the headers just for that file without the need to create a subdomain or host it on another server without Wordpress?

Comment: Have you tried registering a REST API endpoint? Most of your `server.php` code could be copy pasted into it as is. Having standalone PHP files that bootstrap WP is a big security risk, there are better ways to do this that are faster/safer/easier

Comment: No I haven't but I will try. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I have looked into it but I don't think this will work with my setup since I have some external included files and some json files, as well which I constantly need to change. Will get a new SSL and make a subdomain to host my files.